# How to Use DI to get a final variable as @PostMapping's path

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a final class Constants, which holds some final data.

```java
@Component
public final class Constants {
    public final String TOKEN;
    public final String HOST;
    public final String TELEGRAM;

    public Constants(@Value("${myapp.bot-token}") String token,
                     @Value("${myapp.host}") String host) {
        this.TOKEN = token;
        this.HOST = host;
        this.TELEGRAM = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + TOKEN;
    }

}
```

The problem is that, when I want to use a variable as `@PostMapping` path, I faced this error:

```
Attribute value must be constant
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class Controller {

    private final Constants constants;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(Constants constants) {
        this.constants = constants;
    }

    @PostMapping(constants.TOKEN)// Problem is here
    public ResponseEntity<?> getMessage(@RequestBody String payload) {
        return new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

I've tried to load `TOKEN` in my controller class but faced the same issue.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class Controller {

    @Value("${myapp.bot-token}") String token
    private String token;

    @PostMapping(token)// Problem is here
    public ResponseEntity<?> getMessage(@RequestBody String payload) {
        return new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

When I do something like this the problem will gone. But I don't want to declare my token in source-code.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class Controller {

    private final String TOKEN = "SOME-TOKEN";

    @PostMapping(TOKEN)// No problem
    public ResponseEntity<?> getMessage(@RequestBody String payload) {
        return new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Can anyone please give me a solution to this?

Comment: Hi Soroush, were you looking specifically using the final variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to paste string with property path inside @PostMapping annotation. Like this

```
@GetMapping(value = "${app.path}")
public String hello() {
    return "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can only use a constant (i.e. a final static variable) as the parameter for an annotation.

   Example:

   ```
   @Component
   class Constants {
       public final static String FACEBOOK = "facebook";
   }

   @RestController
   class Controller {
       @PostMapping(Constants.FACEBOOK) 
       public ResponseEntity<ResponseBody> getMessage(@RequestBody String payload) {
           return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
       }
   }
   ```
2. You must use builder pattern(use Lombok for ease) and freeze the value that you are getting from the `properties` and then use that in your program.